# Expected sum of Hamming distances in set of random strings

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, probabilistic-method

Thee Hamming distance $H(S_1, S_2)$ between two binary strings $S_1, S_2$ of length $n$ is the number of positions on which the two strings disagree.
It is straightforward to show that if $S_1, S_2$ are two random strings of length $n$, the expected Hamming distance $\mathbb{E}[H(S_1, S_2)]$ is $n/2$.

Now, say I'd like to have a set of $k$ strings $S =\{S_1, \ldots, S_k\}$ such that 
for every $S_i \in S$, the average distance between $S_i$ and the other strings of $S$ is at least $n/2$.  In other words, for every $S_i \in S$, $\sum_{j \neq i} H(S_i, S_j) \geq (k - 1)n/2$.

Actually, I'm not really interested in constructing $S$.  Rather, I'm interested in whether the following argumentation, which shows that $S$ exists, is valid - for it seems to me that there is a hole to fill.  This came up during an informal discussion on math stuff, and I couldn't refute the argument on the spot.  Here's the argument.

> We show that such an $S$ exists by picking $S_1, \ldots, S_k$ randomly
>    (uniformly and independently).  Then for any $S_i \in S$, the exected
>    sum of distances $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i \neq j} H(S_i, S_j)] = 
>   (k - 1) \mathbb{E}[H(S_i, S_j)] = (k - 1)n/2$, by linearity of expectation. 
>    Thus there is a set of strings $S$ such that 
>     $\sum_{i \neq
>  j}H(S_i, S_j) \geq (k - 1)n/k$. Since this holds for every $S_i \in
>  S$, we deduce that there exists a set of strings $S$ such that every
>    string $S_i \in S$ has $\sum_{i \neq j}H(S_i, S_j) \geq (k - 1)n/2$

The part that's bugging me is the end, which basically says "since this holds for every $S_i$, then there is a $S$ in which every $S_i$ has the desired sum".
The argument shows that for any $S_i$, there is a $S$ having the desired sum.  But does this show that there is a single $S$ satisfying *every* $S_i$ simultaneously?

Comment: Note that there's another error, apart from the one you're rightly pointing out: You wanted a set of strings, and the argument applies to ordered tuples of strings, with repetitions allowed. This isn't a problem, though, since disallowing repetitions increases the expected Hamming distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't. The argument merely shows that there are $k$ possibly different sets that each have the desired property for one of the $S_i$.

Comment: OK, since we share the same point of view, I trust you, thank you!

Comment: @ManuelLafond: This is perhaps easier to see (so you don't have to take it on trust ;-) in the case of uniformly randomly picking an ordered $k$-tuple $a$ of different integers from $0$ to $n$. Then each component of $a$ has expected value $n/2$, so for each component $a_i$ there must be a tuple with $a_i\ge n/2$, but obviously this doesn't imply that there's a tuple in which all components are $\ge n/2$ (and in fact there isn't for sufficiently large $k$).

Comment: Yes, that's a great counter-argument!  Exactly what I need :)  Thanks again